# Different amount of label and data in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to generate a chart that might not have the same amount of data and labels.

For example, I have a label for each month, but maybe for the month of March or August I do not have a value.

I tried with the following code:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Test',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      data: [{
        'x': 'Apr',
        'y': 40
      }, {
        'x': 'July',
        'y': 70
      }, {
        'x': 'Dec',
        'y': 120
      }]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'My Test'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

But it displays the value in the wrong position as it is in the image.

[image: Image of chart with bar in the wrong position.]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But it displays the value in the wrong position as it is in the image

That's because the `indexes` of the data you provided corresponds to the first 3 values of your labels.

**Solution #1:**

To resolve this, you have the even out the length of the labels to the length of your data set by providing placeholder values for the lacking points in your data.

**Do not use zeros as placeholder for non-existent values in your dataset if you don't want Chartjs to display the chart data in this manner.** [*See the short grayed-out areas indicating the zero values.*]

[image: See the short grayed-out areas indicating the zero values.]

So the better way to handle this is to provide `null` values instead. See working example below.

```js
const labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const data = [{'x':'Apr', 'y':40},{'x':'July', 'y':70},{'x':'Dec', 'y':120}];

const filledMonths = data.map((month) => month.x);
const dataset = labels.map(month => {
  const indexOfFilledData = filledMonths.indexOf(month);
 if( indexOfFilledData!== -1) return data[indexOfFilledData].y;
  return null;
});
console.log(dataset);
```

**Solution #2:** In Chartjs > 2.x you can use [`time scale`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis)

If you have a lot of data and don't want to usey placeholder values for your missing data then **you set your `xAxes` scale type as `time` in your chart options.**

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956823/3567063) using this implementation.

---

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any value for any month, provide 0 as data for the same.

```
var options = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                datasets:[
                    {
                        label: 'Test',
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                        data: [0,0,0,40,0,0,70,0,0,0,0,120]
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'My Test'
                },
                scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
            }
        }
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Answer (score -2):

Chart.js supports all of the formats that Moment.js accepts ('MMM YYYY').
Just adding the year should do the trick.